# groovyc adds statements after ireturn in bytecode

Tags: groovy, bytecode

Simple experiment where a method adds two ints.

First in Java:

```
gravadlax@durum byte_me> cat Add.java
public class Add {
    public int add(int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Which leads to nothing unexpected in the bytecode (irrelevant parts removed):

```
gravadlax@durum byte_me> javac -g:none Add.java && javap -c Add

  public int add(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: iadd
       3: ireturn
```

Now in Groovy, using `@CompileStatic`:

```
gravadlax@durum byte_me> cat Add.groovy
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class Add {
    int add(int i, int j) {
        i + j
    }
}
```

And the bytecode:

```
gravadlax@durum byte_me> groovyc Add.groovy && javap -c Add

  public int add(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: iadd
       3: ireturn
       4: ldc           #34                 // int 0
       6: ireturn
```

Now that's weird. What are 4 and 6 doing here? Not that it would change anything in practice, but out of curiosity, why would those two extra statements be generated?

Groovy Version: 2.3.4 JVM: 1.7.0_60 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: What version of groovy?

Comment: It's probably the implicit return, do you get different results if you `return i + j`?

Comment: @tim_yates Edited, I knew I was forgetting something. It's not `return`; I actually thought it could be the cause of the issue in the first place and I removed it. Makes no difference. Same for a trailing `;`: no influence.

Comment: It's probably just a quirk of the way grooyc is implemented. I'd suggest looking at the Groovy source to see if you can find the issue.